# New provisioning profile not displays under code signing

Tags: ios6, provisioning-profile

I created a provisioning profile and installed in first time without any issue. After I have to modify the profile and re install it again. I delete that old profile from the organizer and double cli on the nw provisioning file. Then it dislayed under the provisioning in the organizer. But now it not displaying in the `Code signing` how can I solve this. Please help me.

Thanks